# Error connecting CICS from websphere liberty profile

Tags: websphere-liberty

I´m trying to deploy a war that connects to CISC into a Websphere Liberty Profile app server 8.5.5. It works perfectly in WAS, however there is a feature missing but I don´t know which.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.etools.marshall.util.ConversionUtils
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClassCommonLibraryClassLoaders(AppClassLoader.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClass(AppClassLoader.java:276)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:876)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findOrDelegateLoadClass(AppClassLoader.java:482)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:443)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:846)
```

Comment: hi, can you please update your question with additional information such as: the server.xml config you are using (minus any sensitive data such as passwords), and also the full stack trace of the CNFE you have mentioned in your original post? Also, Liberty 8.5.5 is an extremely old version of Liberty and you should try to use a newer version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the "Record" class from the development tools (such as Rational Application Developer).  In Liberty these classes are not bundled with the runtime and need to be imported.  The instructions are here:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7K4U_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/twlp_dat_radrecdata.html

This includes the conversion utils that your stack trace is showing.

Comment: I managed to fix that problem but I have a new one ... I´ll raise another post. Thanks for your help.